# Is there a beginners' guide to cross browser CSS?

Tags: html, css, browser

My site is different in Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Internet Explorer.

How do I change my site to work with all them browsers? Do I need to make different stylesheets for each?

For example, I used css3 to make a CSS circle shape but Internet Explorer doesn't support it as it makes the circle a square. How do you get around this?

Comment: Did you mean 'square'? Because otherwise that's quite an impressive function for IE (Wikipedia entry for '[quire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_quire#Quire)').

Comment: So can i not make a circle shape with css2?

Comment: Not in any way that I can think of, no.

Comment: so how do people have css circles shown on internet explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help: http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/cross-browser-consistency-a-beginners-guide/

Comment: Thanks! Can i make a circle shape with css2? because in chrome it shows a circle (ccs3) but in safari and firefox and ie it shows a square

Answer (score 1):

Internet explorer has most of the issues, I found [this](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/internet-explorer.shtml) site helpful and I hope you do too!

Comment: Ah thanks! So can i not make a circle shape with css2?

Answer (score 0):

I use Less ( http://lesscss.org/ ) to make CSS3 cross-browser.

However, you can usually just put all CSS3 in one file. `-moz-linear-gradient`, for example, will be completely ignored by Safari, IE, and pretty much every browser there is out there.